# SimpleXML Dynamic Attributes

Tags: php, xml, loops, foreach, simplexml

I'm trying to figure out how to generate the code for this.

```
$revImages = $revXML->addChild('images');
$revImage = $revImages->addChild('image');
$revImage->addAttribute('src', '001.jpg');
```

the last line is the static entry for what I need. Is there a `foreach` statement I can use to auto generate that last line based on the images from a directory so it outputs as such:

```
<images>
    <image src = "001.jpg"/>
    <image src = "002.jpg"/>
    <image src = "003.jpg"/>
    <image src = "004.jpg"/>
    <image src = "005.jpg"/>
    <image src = "006.jpg"/>
    <image src = "007.jpg"/>
    <image src = "008.jpg"/>
    <image src = "009.jpg"/>
    <image src = "010.jpg"/>
</images>
```

Comment: With a simple `foreach`. Where does `001.jpg` comes from?

Comment: from the image names in the directory. Rather I need to look in a directory and grab the image names and output them as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution using [***glob***](https://www.php.net/glob) function (to find pathnames matching a pattern):

```
foreach (glob("/path/to/directory/*.jpg") as $filepath) {
    $src = basename($filepath);
    $revImages
       ->addChild('image')
       ->addAttribute('src', $src)
    ;
}
```

Comment: That did it 100% just one more question if i may? how can I just have the file name and not the entire url path show up as such?

Comment: <image src="001.jpg"/> instead of -> <image src="./website/assets/001.jpg"/>

Comment: I tried $revImage->addAttribute('src', basename($filepath)); didnt really work

Comment: got it for anyone who needs it my mistake

Comment: foreach (glob($path . "*.jpg") as $filepath) {
    $filepath = basename($filepath);
    $revImage = $revImages->addChild('image');
    $revImage->addAttribute('src', basename($filepath));
}

Answer (score 1):

This is it:

```
$revImages = $revXML->addChild('images');
foreach ($some_data as $value) {
    // yes, everytime you need to create new `$revImage`
    $revImage = $revImages->addChild('image');
    $revImage->addAttribute('src', $value);
}
```

where `$some_data` is array of values that you have.

**Update:**

```
if ($handle = opendir($path)) { 
    // create parent node before while-loop
    $revImages = $revXML->addChild('images'); 
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) { 
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") { 
            // yes, everytime you need to create new $revImage 
            $revImage = $revImages->addChild('image'); 

            // `$entry` is already a filename, there's no need to iterate over it
            $revImage->addAttribute('src', $entry); 
        } 
    } 
    closedir($handle); 
}
```

Comment: so I have to set the $some_data to a search function as such [code]$some_data = if (is_dir($path)){
  if ($dh = opendir($path)){
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){
      echo $file . "<br>";
    closedir($dh);
  }
};[/code]

Comment: Yes, set `$some_data` and iterate over it

Comment: got it ill give it a shot and report back thanks again for your help and quick response

Comment: Why not just add the code in the while loop directly when you scan the folder? No need to create an extra array which you then just iterate over with another loop.

Comment: im trying this with no luck if ($handle = opendir($path)) {

    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {

        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {

            $revImages = $revXML->addChild('images');
foreach ($entry as $value) {
    // yes, everytime you need to create new `$revImage`
    $revImage = $revImages->addChild('image');
    $revImage->addAttribute('src', $value);
}
        }
    }

    closedir($handle);
}

Comment: `$entry` is __not__ an array, it is already a filename. See the update.